# Синтаксис java точка перед пустым пространством что означает

Tags: java

```
     var next = InlineKeyboardButton.builder()
        .text("Next").callbackData("next")           
        .build();
 var next = InlineKeyboardButton.builder()
        .text("Next").callbackData("next")           
        .build();
```

Comment: Так можно оформлять перенос на новую строку, чтобы строка не была слишком длинной: `var next = InlineKeyboardButton.builder().text("Next").callbackData("next").build();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Эта точка НЕ *перед пустым пространством*, а для вызова метода у объекта, который возвращается из предыдущего метода -- так называемый ["гладкий" или "плавный" программный интерфейс](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

Шаблон проектирования `Builder`, показанный в вопросе,-- один из наиболее популярных способов применения "плавного" интерфейса для создания объектов со множеством параметров ([статья на хабре](https://habr.com/ru/companies/otus/articles/552412/)).

Упрощенно говоря, для некоего класса `InlineKeyboard` создаётся класс-строитель `InlineKeyboardBuilder`, с теми же полями, что и поля в основном классе, но сеттеры которого возвращают ссылку на текущий экземпляр билдера.
Также реализуется метод `build()`, возвращающий экземпляр нужного класса.

```java
public class InlineKeyboardBuilder {
    private String text;
    private String callbackData;

    public InlineKeyboardBuilder() {}

    public InlineKeyboardBuilder text(String text) { 
        this.text = text;
        return this;
    }

    public InlineKeyboardBuilder callbackData(String data) {
        this.callbackData = data;
        return this;
    }

    public InlineKeyboard build() {
        return new InlineKeyboard(text, callbackData);
    }
}
```

Классы-билдеры удобно генерить при помощи соответствующей Lombok аннотации [`@Builder`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder).

Comment: Очень хороший ответ, спасибо